# Aggregation, joining, and filtering with many-to-many table

Tags: sql-server

Let's say i have a database of customers who buy materials that are "applicable" to random objects. For example, John buys $10 of "Material X" that is applicable to a car and a house.

```
Customers
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Larry |
+----+-------+

Orders
+---------+------------+-------+----------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | Sales | Material |
+---------+------------+-------+----------+
|       1 |          1 |    10 | x        |
|       2 |          1 |    15 | x        |
|       3 |          1 |     6 | y        |
|       4 |          2 |     3 | x        |
|       5 |          2 |    25 | y        |
+---------+------------+-------+----------+
```

My `Materials` table originally looked like this

```
+----------+-------------------------+
| Material |      Applicability      |
+----------+-------------------------+
| x        | car, house, plane, bike |
| y        | car, bike               |
+----------+-------------------------+
```

When I need to display what materials John buys and which objects that material is applicable to, my query is this.

```
Select ID, Name, sum(Sales), Material, Applicability
FROM Customers a 
INNER JOIN Orders b on a.ID = b.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Materials c on b.Material = c.Material
WHERE Name = 'John' 
GROUP BY ID, Name, Material, Applicability
```

The result

```
+----+------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
| ID | Name | Total Sales | Material |      Applicability      |
+----+------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
|  1 | John |           25 | x        | car, house, plane, bike |
|  1 | John |            6 | y        | car, bike               |
+----+------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

The comma separated values (i know it violates many rules) was convenient, because when parsing the applicability i could simply split the string by commas and then i had a list of applicability objects.

Now it's been decided to normalize the `Materials` table. The table relationship is many to many. A material can be applicable to many objects, and objects can contain many materials.

```
+----------+---------------+
| Material | Applicability |
+----------+---------------+
| x        | car           |
| x        | house         |
| x        | plane         |
| x        | bike          |
| y        | car           |
| y        | bike          |
+----------+---------------+
```

This normalization has disrupted my existing query, it causes the `sum(sales)` result to be a multiple of however many objects the material is applicable to.

Example.

```
+----+------+-------------+----------+---------------+
| ID | Name | Total Sales | Material | Applicability |
+----+------+-------------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | John |          25 | x        | car           |
|  1 | John |          25 | x        | house         |
|  1 | John |          25 | x        | plane         |
|  1 | John |          25 | x        | bike          |
|  1 | John |           6 | y        | car           |
|  1 | John |           6 | y        | bike          |
+----+------+-------------+----------+---------------+
```

Now it looks John has bought $100 of material x, when he has really only bought $25. I need to show the user John's purchase of material x, as well as x's applicability.

The main problem is when i need to find out what John buys, but also **filter by applicability**.

```
Select ID, Name, sum(Sales), Material, Applicability
FROM Customers a 
INNER JOIN Orders b on a.ID = b.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Materials c on b.Material = c.Material
WHERE Name = 'John' and (applicability = 'car' or applicability = 'bike')
GROUP BY ID, Name, Material, Applicability
```

If any material is applicable to both car and bike, then the aggregate value `sum(sales)` will be doubled.

How do i deal with this duplication? I'm open to getting the result set in a different format, I just want the aggregation results to be correct.

Comment: Do you need to return applicability as well as filter by it? By removing it, you can use a SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

if you group by material, you can select the max sales and group_concat the applicability. this will give one value for the sale of material x with a new column that shows the combined, filtered uses. then a subquery will show the correct sum of sales per material (or order, or however else you decide to group).

I added group by OrderID in the subquery since it seems like you're looking for John's lifetime sales?

```
select ID, Name, sum(Sales), Material, Applicability
(Select ID, Name, max(Sales) as Sales, Material, group_concat(Applicability separator ', ') as Applicability
FROM Customers a 
INNER JOIN Orders b on a.ID = b.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Materials c on b.Material = c.Material
WHERE Name = 'John' and (applicability = 'car' or applicability = 'bike')
GROUP BY OrderID, ID, Name, Material) sub
GROUP BY ID, Name, Material
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID, Name, sum(Sales), Material, Applicability
FROM Customers a 
INNER JOIN Orders b on a.ID = b.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Materials c on b.Material = c.Material
WHERE Name = 'John' and applicability = 'car'
GROUP BY ID, Name, Material, Applicability 
UNION
Select ID, Name, sum(Sales), Material, Applicability
FROM Customers a 
INNER JOIN Orders b on a.ID = b.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Materials c on b.Material = c.Material
WHERE Name = 'John' and applicability = 'bike' 
GROUP BY ID, Name, Material, Applicability
```